# WordPress: Load JavaScript / JQuery after dynamic page content loads in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick, cycle

I'm trying to create a one-page WordPress based site with page content being loaded into a div onClick. However, since the JavaScript has already been loaded well before the page content is loaded, the scripts don't work.

The temp site is here: http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~swstr0/

If you click on CLIENTS-->Who We Work With you'll see the problem. A logo slider that doesn't slide. No arrows, and depending on the browser, the links don't work.

Probably because this script already loaded? http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~swstr0/wp-content/plugins/logo-slider/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=3.9.1

Here's the code I'm currently using to get the div to slide down (or up) and load page content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$("li.btn-slide a").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
    var post_id  = $(this).attr("rel");

    $("#page-con").html("loading...")
                  .load(post_url, function() { // content loaded callback

        var pageconHeight = $("#page-con").height();  // Find the height of the content inside #panel
         $("#panel").animate({height: pageconHeight}, "slow"); // Animate the height of #panel

    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

When you run the slider script, it applies the slider effect to the **existing** elements. If you put new content in your page, you need to reapply the script.

After this line:

```
$("#panel").animate({height: pageconHeight}, "slow"); // Animate the height of #panel
```

Add

```
$('#idOfYourLoadedContent').cycle();
```

Comment: Well, I guess #idOfYourLoadedContent would be #page-con in my instance. I tried that but all I got was errors in console like this: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector